# VBA Writes Extra Lines When Impossible To Do So

Tags: excel, vba

I was wokring on the piece of code below, and had it functioning correctly. Somehow a line has changed and meant now it fails to function

I have a table of tags and weightings like so:

```
Tag   | Weight
---------------
Sport |  1
Music |  1
```

And then another table of users, with tag + weight

```
User  |  Tag   |  Weight
```

---

The cell(j, "B") contains the username, as does the cell(2,"C") in the other worksheet

I am using the following code:

```
Sub swipeleft()

LastRowUser = Worksheets(13).Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row
LastRowInput = Worksheets(14).Range("F65536").End(xlUp).Row
LastRowUser = LastRowUser + 1

newcount = 1

For j = 2 To LastRowUser
    For k = 9 To LastRowInput
        If Worksheets(14).Cells(k, "F") = Worksheets(13).Cells(j, "C") And Worksheets(13).Cells(j, "B") = Worksheets(14).Cells(2, "C") Then
            Worksheets(13).Cells(j, "D") = Worksheets(13).Cells(j, "D") - Worksheets(14).Cells(k, "G")
        ElseIf Not Worksheets(13).Cells(j, "B") = Worksheets(14).Cells(2, "C") Then
            Worksheets(13).Cells(newcount + LastRowUser, "C") = Worksheets(14).Cells(k, "F")
            Worksheets(13).Cells(newcount + LastRowUser, "D") = Worksheets(14).Cells(k, "G") * (-1)
            Worksheets(13).Cells(newcount + LastRowUser, "B") = Worksheets(14).Cells(2, "C")
            newcount = newcount + 1
        End If
    Next k
Next j

End Sub
```

This adds the rows when data is not present, but for some reason after the first run it keeps adding exponentially more rows, even though the second else condition is not met?

> UPDATED FROM COMMENTS BELOW

Here is the user input page (Worksheet 14):

[image]

Here is the user database page (Worksheet 13):

[image]

On the user database page I would like it to add the two rows that dont exist (Music, Dance) and add the Sports tag weighting (-1) from the input page to the current value in user database page

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: In Cell (2, "C") I have entered my username 'darnich'. When I run this macro I would like it to find wherever a tag already exists against my name, in this case it would add the weight to the current USER|TAG|WEIGHT table. If it does not find (name && tag) in the table (ie if the record of that user with that tag doesnt exist anywhere in the USER|TAG|WEIGHT table) then a new record is created in that table

Comment: Sorry I am still unable to visualize your problem. You say you are entering the username in Col C. But as per your table Col C has "Weight" or does your table start from Col C? Perhaps a screenshot of the data might help?

Comment: Here is the user input page (Worksheet 14): [here](http://i.imgur.com/MPl6SWV.png)  
Here is the user database page (Worksheet 13): [here](http://i.imgur.com/O669X27.png).
  
On the user database page I would like it to add the two rows that dont exist (Music, Dance) and add the Sports tag weighting (-1) from the input page to the current value in user database page

Comment: IS this the output you are looking in sheet(13) http://wikisend.com/download/498432/1.png

Comment: yep thats what im looking for. When you run it again I would like it to add the value of the tag from Worksheet(14) to the existing record in Worksheet (13) as well

Comment: you need 3 iterating variables to achieve that. It's going to be super slow with a large amount of data because you do `i*j*k` iterations. You need a totally different approach. I recommend starting with collections

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

**Code:**

```
Dim AR
Dim nWeight As Long
Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
Dim LRowWsI As Long, LRowWsO As Long, NewRowWsO As Long

Sub swipeleft()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Set wsI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(14)
    Set wsO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(13)

    LRowWsI = wsI.Range("F" & wsI.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    LRowWsO = wsO.Range("B" & wsI.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    NewRowWsO = LRowWsO + 1

    AR = wsI.Range("F9:G" & LRowWsI).Value

    With wsO
        For i = LBound(AR) To UBound(AR)
            For j = 2 To LRowWsO
                If RecordExists(wsI.Range("C2").Value, AR(i, 1)) Then
                    .Range("D" & j).Value = AR(i, 2)
                Else
                    .Range("B" & NewRowWsO).Value = wsI.Range("C2").Value
                    .Range("C" & NewRowWsO).Value = AR(i, 1)
                    .Range("D" & NewRowWsO).Value = AR(i, 2)
                    NewRowWsO = NewRowWsO + 1
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    End With
End Sub

Function RecordExists(sUser As Variant, sTag As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim a As Long

    With wsO
        For a = 2 To LRowWsO
            If .Range("B" & a).Value = sUser And .Range("C" & a).Value = sTag Then
                RecordExists = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Function
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: If I run this more than once, the data repeats itself in Sheet 13 so I get hundreds of rows of the same data, whereas I would like it just to update the matching records.

Comment: Can there be more users?

Comment: Yes the cell C2 in Worksheet 14 can contain any name, that may or may not exist in Sheet 13

Comment: can you upload a sample excel file that I can play with? if yes, then can you upload it in wikisend.com and share the link here?

Comment: wikisend is blocked where I am but ive used FileSnack instead http://snk.to/f-chi0bjmh. As you can see its very basic. I would like to use it to add more users+tag+weighting to Worksheet13 whenever I change the name and tags in Worksheet14

Comment: This has only one user. I already have this. Can you create a realistic sample?

Comment: The user would input their name in the field C2, so just using any name in there will suffice

Comment: What I was want to see that Col C can have Nick, Joe, Frank etc from C2 to C4 or more?

Comment: The user input name would always be entered into C2, so whatever name is in that cell is compared to the list in Worksheet 13, and the tags either have their weighting changed or added as a new line